# How I can see my shares from remote through Internet

Tags: networking

I have many shares in many different computers with Ubuntu, Windows and Android. I have already installed Samba and it's working properly. All the shares I could access either from Ubuntu, Android or Windows.

But all I could do within from my own network. Is there any way, so I could see all of my shares from remote, through Internet? May be with any commands or using any browser?

Pls help me in this issue. Thanking you in advance.

Raihan

Answer (score 0):

#### Rule out alternatives

Before you open SAMBA access to the rest of the world, have you thought about using a more secure service that's designed for wide-area network usage?  If I'm not mistaken, SAMBA is designed for local/secure-ish networks, whereas alternatives, such as sshfs, scp, sftp, may be a better solution for you.

#### Ensure SAMBA lockdown

Before allowing SAMBA to be accessed remotely (over the Internet), make sure you set it up in such a way that you can control access to your files. [How-To](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/samba-fileprint-security.html)

#### Routing

In order for remote computers (those outside of your LAN) to access your SAMBA machine(s), you will need to set up port forwarding such that the TCP ports 135, 139, 445 as well as the UDP ports 135-139 are forwarded to your SAMBA machine.  How will you allow access to multiple machines?  I don't know.

#### Closing

Again, please look at alternatives to this solution, as I don't believe anybody would recommend using SAMBA over WAN.

Comment: Hi guys, Sry, a bit late to reply u.I was a bit bzy with something else. Anyway, I am using SAMBA within my local network, not for WAN. I am looking something, through which I could see all of my shares from anywhere in the world and get access to them. By-the-way, I don't know how to lock SAMBA as well, and how to test that SAMBA is locked from outside world.

Comment: Have you looked into sshfs?  You can mount remote filesystems/directories over ssh.  Much easier to secure than SAMBA.

Comment: Oh, sorry!!! I was away for a long time. Yeah, I tried ssh, that's great. But how can I use this from Windows machine, please help me on this. Thnx in advance.